# How to check if there is an image added to the dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqwGoP)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
                <span>Upload or drag patient photo here</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    url: "#",
    maxFiles:1,
init: function() {

      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
        alert("You are not allowed to chose more than 1 file!");
            this.removeFile(file);

      });

}   
});



var fileName = $('#profilePicture').val();
var mockFile = { name: fileName, size: 12345 };
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eubcS91wUNg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAL0/iE1Hduvbbqc/photo.jpg?sz=104");
```

What I want to do is to check if there is already a loaded image.

For example:

```
if(is an image loaded from the first?)
{
   alert("you have already image, delete it first");
}else{
   alert("you can upload image now");
}
```

Basically they do not want the user can put another picture if there is already loaded.

As you can see in my example, the first load an image ... if you want to load another one, allowed us (I do not want it).

Is there any way this can be restricted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove or disable the dropzone in the event that is triggered when a file is dropped.

Comment: You can edit my example please?
I do not really understand

Answer (score 0):

DropZone provides the methods [`enable()` and `disable()`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods), which you can use to control the usage of it.

You can use the [`drop` or `addedFile`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list) events to call this function:

```
init: function() {
  this.on("addedFile", function(file) {
    // do what you want with the added file
    this.disable();  // disable the dropzone to prevent more files
  });
}
```

Comment: Here check if the image exists or not?
I am interested in how they make their condition

Answer (score 0):

Works for me , if the image is already uploaded in the dropzone , it does not allow me to add more .

```
 this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                /* 
                Valid only in the dropzone . If a repetitive document shows ALERT and the previous item will disappear.(Sorry my English).
                */
                if (this.files.length) {
                    var i, len, pre;
                    for (i = 0, len = this.files.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
                        if (this.files[i].name == file.name && this.files[i].size == file.size && this.files[i].lastModifiedDate.toString() == file.lastModifiedDate.toString()) {
                            alert("You have already image, delete it first")
                            return (pre = file.previewElement) != null ? pre.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Espero que de algo te halla ayudado.